# does this counting property have a name?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, terminology, monotone-functions

Suppose $\gamma:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ is increasing and $$\gamma(n+1)=\gamma(n)\implies\gamma(n+k)=\gamma(n)\mbox{ for all } k\in\mathbb{N}.$$

(1) In addition to being increasing one could say that $\gamma$ is “uniquely eventually constant” but that's too unwieldy. Is a better term currently in use?

(2) Are there nontrivial examples of finite counting problems where without knowing the answer, one can (rigorously) know in advance that the counting function $\gamma$ satisfies the above, thus reducing the problem to finding an $n$ such that $\gamma(n+1)=\gamma(n)?$

Edit added 13 Oct 2022:

This question is a more-to-the-point version of a question I asked a couple days ago in MO: [How rigorously can we apply the data supplied by this nonstandard attack on Kuratowski's closure-complement problem?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/432246/how-rigorously-can-we-apply-the-data-supplied-by-this-nonstandard-attack-on-kura)

Comment: First of all, that function is not strictly increasing. It is at most non-decreasing.

Comment: @Tbw https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straw_man

Comment: If anyone sees fit to change increasing to non-decreasing be my guest...they're synonymous AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a name for this property, but an example that occurs in practice is given by the sequences of dimensions $d_k = \dim \ker(M - \lambda I)^k$ where $M$ is a square matrix and $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $M$. These are the dimensions of spaces of [generalized eigenvectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_eigenvector).